# How to read System.serviceModel in Class Library with Proxy implementation of WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, wcf-binding

I am trying to read service configuration in Class Library from the app.config file of the library. but getting below exception

> Could not find endpoint element with name 'WSHttpBinding_IUsers' and contract 'ISGP.Plugins.SolveService.IUsers' 
>   in the ServiceModel client configuration section. 
>   This might be because no configuration file was found for your application,
>    or because no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the client element.

I tried ti implement the below code to read the config and create the client

```
 public class ServiceManager
{
    public static T CreateServiceClient<T>(string configName)
    {
       // string _assemblyLocation = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;

        var configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(
                         new ExeConfigurationFileMap
                         {
                             ExeConfigFilename = "app.config"
                         }, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

        ConfigurationChannelFactory<T> channelFactory = new ConfigurationChannelFactory<T>(configName, configuration, null);
        var client = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
        return client;
    }


}
```

Call this method as below

```
    usersClient= (UsersClient)ServiceManager.CreateServiceClient<IUsersChannel>("WSHttpBinding_IUsers");
  usersClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = userName;
  usersClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;
```

But it throws the above exception the app.config file is as below

```
 <system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IUsers">
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" establishSecurityContext="false" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="https://xxxxxx16.prod.xxxxx.local/WebServices/v3/Users.svc"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IUsers"
        contract="ISGP.Plugins.SolveService.IUsers" name="WSHttpBinding_IUsers" />
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please pass the endpoint parameter in the channel factory constructor.

> ConfigurationChannelFactory channelFactory = new
>   ConfigurationChannelFactory(configName, configuration, null);

You can refer to the following code.

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
            fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = "app.config";
            Configuration newConfiguration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            ConfigurationChannelFactory<IService> factory = new ConfigurationChannelFactory<IService>("endpoint1", newConfiguration, new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8000/servicemodelsamples/service"));
            factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "jack";
            factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "123456";
            IService client1 = factory.CreateChannel();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/configuration-channel-factory
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Hi If you see me code I have also done the same way. But only you have "Iservice" do I need to change it.

Comment: When I searched the Internet for a lot of information, I came to a conclusion. There is no built-in support for this in WCF unfortunately.